# Screen off the monitor

Tags: resolution, display

Just got a brand new Samsung SyncMaster 2233sw, a welcome change to my super old crt I used to have. The problem is that the recomended screen resolution is 1920x1080 and any other resolution looks squished and blurry, But if I set it to 1920x1080 about a half an inch on both sides is cut off. The strange thing is, that if I plug in my old CRT and set the resolution to 1920x1080 and then unplug it and plug in my new monitor, everything is fine. But every time I restart my computer I have to do this which is a big pain. Also I am running on an onboard video card if that has anything to do with it. Anyway to fix this?

Update: The only time when it displays properly is when I trick my computer into thinking that the monitor I am currently using is the old CRT, If I have windows (yes it is MS windows) detect that the monitor I'm using is the SyncMaster it stretches out horizontaly and cuts off a half inch at both ends even if I press the Auto button on the side. (Tried updating my display driver (ATI RADEON XPRESS 200 SERIES) and windows manager said that it was up to date), Also updated my monitor driver, also no help, one interesting thing though when I do the hack and convince windows that its the CRT and then detect my monitor type, the screen resolution defaults to 1280x1040, but still says that 1920x1080 is recomended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to try and find an update to your video driver.

See if Windows Update doesn't have a suggestion, but even better is to check on the Samsung site.

Comment: It was the video card ATI RADEON XPRESS 200 SERIES, I had to go and get this software called ATI Catalyst off of AMD's website, I installed it an now everything is working right. Thanks!

Comment: As a side note; I have samsung monitors and they came with some tru colour software or somthing - they recommend installing it but I never do; this may provide some details to the graphics card regarding the correct settings/frequencies etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the X Windowing System or its descendants like Xorg, xvidtune would work.

If you're using MS Windows, is it detecting your monitor correctly?

Comment: Oops I am not useing the x windowing system and I did not fully understand what it was. It would be interesting to boot into linux just to see what happens with the screen.

Comment: @josh completely different drivers and monitor detection system?  it'd probably work fine.

Comment: X window works fine but sadly, slightly unsupported by Microsoft

Answer (score 0):

Is there a button on the monitor labelled "Auto"?  Press it.  It should auto-center the display.

Edit: So the monitor's auto-tune doesn't help.  I assume you've also tried the monitor's manual controls.

I have to agree with harrymc, it sounds like a driver issue.  Check for an updated video driver, and you might also check that Windows is using the latest driver for the monitor as well.  Here's [Samsung's support site](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/download/supportDownloadMain.do), and [this may get the driver directly](http://org.downloadcenter.samsung.com/downloadfile/ContentsFile.aspx?CDSite=US&CttFileID=2052232&CDCttType=DR&ModelType=N&ModelName=2233SW&VPath=DR/200811/20081104094536109/SM2233SW.exe).

Comment: Already tried that did not work